# Mapping ASes (Autonomous Systems) to geographical location

Tags: database, networking, geolocation, ip, maxmind

I am looking for a database that maps AS numbers to their locations (latitude and longitude).

One way that I can do is to map an AS number to an IP address, and then map that IP to a location.

Is there any database that directly maps AS numbers to their location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two databases solutions. First is the IP address to ASN. Second is the IP address to Latitude and Longitude.

You can download the free databases from:

https://lite.ip2location.com/database-ip-asn

https://lite.ip2location.com/database-ip-country-region-city-latitude-longitude